# Unable to get updated state using React useContext and useMemo

Tags: reactjs

I want to use React's useContext and useMemo to get the updated value, but the value is returned without being updated from the initialState.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm writing this?

A simple codesandbox can be found below.

`./context/AppContext.js`

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
  useMemo,
  useReducer
} from "react";

export const AppContext = createContext();

export const useAppContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

const initialState = {
  bar: null
};

const SET_APP = "SET_APP";

export const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case SET_APP:
      const { bar } = payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        bar
      };
    default:
      throw Error(
        `Unexpected action type in ElectionContext reducer: '${type}'.`
      );
  }
};

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const appSetter = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: SET_APP, payload: { bar: "bar" } });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={useMemo(
        () => [
          state,
          {
            appSetter
          }
        ],
        [appSetter]
      )}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAppSetter = () => {
  const [, { appSetter }] = useAppContext();
  return appSetter;
};

export const useAppObj = () => {
  const [state] = useAppContext();
  return state;
};

export default AppContextProvider;
```

`App.js`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAppSetter, useAppObj } from "./contexts/AppContext";

export default function App() {
  const appSetter = useAppSetter();
  const { bar } = useAppObj();

  useEffect(() => {
    appSetter();
  });

  const foo = () => {
    console.log(bar);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={foo}>console</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/peaceful-cloud-rn4cs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You forgot to add the codesandbox link

Comment: I am sorry, just edited the post with code and link.